# Unable to launch turtlebot_playground on indigo

Tags: ros, turtlebot-gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Launching turtlebot_playground on indigo (Ubuntu Trusty) throws up the errors:

```
[ERROR] [1400811137.391203936]: Failed to load nodelet [/cmd_vel_mux] of type [yocs_cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet]: Could not find library corresponding to plugin yocs_cmd_vel_mux/CmdVelMuxNodelet. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
[FATAL] [1400811137.391468550]: Service call failed!
[ERROR] [1400811137.540924502]: Failed to load nodelet [/depthimage_to_laserscan] of type [depthimage_to_laserscan/DepthImageToLaserScanNodelet]: Could not find library corresponding to plugin depthimage_to_laserscan/DepthImageToLaserScanNodelet. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
[FATAL] [1400811137.541236510]: Service call failed!
```

despite building both yocs_cmd_vel and depthimage_to_laserscan libraries.

> What more  should I do to prevent the above errors? Or do you recommend me to downgrade to hydro (if that's possible on Trusty)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168401/unable-to-launch-turtlebot_playground-on-indigo/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lily1](https://answers.ros.org/users/30060/lily1/) on 2017-04-18**:
Hi, I am having exactly the same problem. Did sourcing the bash file solve the problem for you? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"despite building" sounds like you are doing a source checkout of these repositories -- have you sourced the correct setup.bash to get these packages on your ros package path?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1